# Difficulties using htaccess deny, allow options in MAMP

Tags: .htaccess, mamp

I want to test my htaccess on a localhost MAMP site.

However, I cannot get the allow ips to override the deny all setting. Similar settings work correctly on my production sites.

Here is what I have now:

```
  <Limit GET>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  allow from 127.0.0.1
  allow from 192.
  </Limit>
```

When I attempt to access the site with these settings I get blocked. If I comment out the deny statement no problem. It looks as though the allow from statements are not overriding the deny all.
Is this a MAMP problem or am I getting the syntax wrong?